# Disabling core dumps for a certain user or shell session without root

Tags: linux, systemd, core-dump

I'm working on a large C++ project. While testing it, I frequently get a core dumped from the main process. This produces a lot of uninteresting core dumps saved within `systemd` and it takes useful disk space.

Is it possible under Linux running `systemd` to disable core-dumps from being recorded only temporarily for a certain user or a perhaps even better only in a certain tty or a certain shell session?

It seems reasonable to me that a user should have the option to disable core-dumps recordings if he/she is about to run a program that dumps a core frequently and he doesn't want to fill the disk space, without the root's intervention.

Comment: core-dump ? Isn't that a kernel behavior which can be turned off for whole userspace? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to edit `/etc/profile` and add a line:

```
ulimit -c 0
```

to this? If you are not root, you could tell the people to run this command by hand.

BTW: most Linux distros make a coredump limit of 0 the default, so debugging on a typical Lnux system does not work unless you type

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

in your shell.

The `ulimit` command internally calls the `setrlimit()` syscall that sets up settings in the process that are inherited by all children. Any program may call `setrlimit()`, not only the shell.

Any of the children in theory may change these settings and create a new inheritance line. So make sure, that e.g. no shell is called in the middle that changes the value again. This may e.g. happen in case that a call to `ulimit` is in one of the startup scripts of the shell.

Comment: +1  for the last paragraph.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, just for clarification: `where ulimit` gives me `shell built-in command` - I assume that it works per shell session and not per login session.

Comment: It works for the shell and all it's children. As long as none of the processes changes the settings.

Comment: ulimit -c 0 does not reliably avoid coredump generation on linux. If the system is setup to pipe coredumps into a program (like systemd-coredump, etc) linux ignores the ulimit (as it is not writing a file?). The way to disable coredump generation even in that case is using prctl to set PR_SET_DUMPABLE to 0.
I think systemd-coredump itself might disable disk storage with 0 ulimit, but not all crash reporting software might respect ulimit.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer won't work for systems that use `systemd-coredump` via a pipe in the `kernel.core_pattern` sysctl parameter.  (As described by @textshell in the comments.)  In those cases, the kernel isn't technically writing the file, so it doesn't respect the core file size limit.

To prevent coredumps on systemd-coredump systems, drop a configuration file in `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf.d/no-corefiles.conf`:

```
[Coredump]
Storage=none
```

The configuration takes effect the next time systemd-coredump runs to process a core.  One side benefit of this approach: the backtraces are still listed in `coredumpctl`.